# How to define the text color of all children in an Android Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently filling a TableLayout with data from external sources. After creating the TableRows and TextViews programmatically, their text color is set to white (seems to be the default).

I know that I can set the color by using `myTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);`, but I am looking for a way to define the color in the XML layout file (**I want to separate visuals from the logic**). Does anyone know how to do this?

My layout (filled with example rows):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/mytable"
  android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  style="@style/AppTheme" >

  <TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="field1" />
    <TextView android:text="field2" />
    <TextView android:text="field3" />
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

My java code:

```
public void updateTable() {

  TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mytable);
  table.removeAllViewsInLayout();
  TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
  TextView text;

  // Add Heading
  text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
  text.setText("Head1");
  text.setTextColor(this.textColor);
  row.addView(text);

  text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
  text.setText("Head2");
  text.setTextColor(this.textColor);
  row.addView(text);

  text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
  text.setText("Head3");
  text.setTextColor(this.textColor);
  row.addView(text);

  table.addView(row);

  for(Data d : this.getData()) {
    TableRow r = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    TextView t1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    TextView t2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    TextView t3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

    t1.setTextColor(this.textColor);
    t2.setTextColor(this.textColor);
    t3.setTextColor(this.textColor);

    t1.setText(d.getData1());
    t2.setText(d.getData2());
    t3.setText(d.getData3());

    r.addView(t1);
    r.addView(t2);
    r.addView(t3);
    table.addView(r);
  }
}
```

Comment: just set text color in TextView <TextView android:text="field1"  android:textColor="@color/your_color"/>

Comment: You can inflate a layout, which contain only a TextView with the textcolor you want instead of creating a TextView programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Create one table_item.xml file of TextView

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ff00ff"/>
```

2.Inflate table_item.xml

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
TextView text = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_item, this);
```

3.Add into TableLayout

```
r.addView(text);
table.addView(r);
```

Comment: Inflating seems to be what I was searching for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F00</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Then just apply that theme to your application in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application […] android:theme="@style/MyTheme">…
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do dynamically then after initializing mytable in java and then proceed as

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mytable.getChildCount(); i++) {
              View view = mytable.getChildAt(i);
              if(view instanceof EditText)//
                 ((EditText)view).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create one common style in style.xml in values folder

> ```
> <style name="WelcomeTextViewTitleStyle">
>         <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/welcome_textview_title_textsize</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
>         <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
>         <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
>         <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
>         <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
>
>     </style>
> ```

1. apply to in your textview

> ```
> <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_title2"
>             style="@style/WelcomeTextViewTitleStyle"
>             android:text="@string/wantToKnow" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
        <TextView android:text="assads"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </TableRow>
```